# Systematic measurement error on a scale centered on zero

Tags: measure-theory, physics

I have the following velocity measurements, where the sign of $V_e$ defines opposing directions of movement in a completely symmetric experimental setting:

\begin{array}{|l|l|r|}
\hline
V_e [cm/s] & V_m [cm/s] & \Delta V [cm/s]\\
\hline 
9 & 9.38 & 0.38\\ 
  8 & 8.491 & 0.491\\ 
  7 & 7.482 & 0.482\\ 
  6 & 6.502 & 0.502\\ 
  5 & 5.726 & 0.726\\ 
  4 & 4.499 & 0.499\\ 
  3 & 2.021 & -0.979\\ 
  2 & 2.34 & 0.34\\ 
  1 & 2.018 & 1.018\\ 
  0 & 0 & 0\\ 
  -1 & -0.501 & -0.499\\ 
  -2 & -2.328 & 0.328\\ 
  -3 & -2.988 & -0.012\\ 
  -4 & -3.503 & -0.497\\ 
  -5 & -4.506 & -0.494\\ 
  -6 & -5.762 & -0.238\\ 
  -7 & -7.479 & 0.479\\ 
  -8 & -7.981 & -0.019\\ 
  -9 & -8.496 & -0.504\\
\hline
\end{array}

In this table, $\Delta V = \left| V_m \right| - \left| V_e \right|$

Running a Student t-test on $\Delta V$, we find that the mean does not significantly differ from zero, under a type I error of 5%. From this result, I conclude that $\Delta V$ is a random error.

The reviewer of my work (I'm an academic student) insists that my method does not account for the direction (*i.e.* the sign of $V$). That is indeed the case, since my test answers a precise question: *Does the measurement method ($V_m$) systematically over/underestimates the true velocity ($||V_e||$)?*

Instead, the reviewer uses $\Delta V = V_m - V_e$ to show that the method significantly overestimates $Ve$, especially when $V_e<0$, using the same t-test. However, I am having trouble finding what specific question such a test answers, and the reviewer's statement is wrong in my opinion.

**What is the correct way of defining $\Delta V$ and discern a systematic measurement error?**

Comment: You may run a regression of the form $V_{m,i}=\alpha_{+}+\alpha_{-}1\{V_{e,i}<0\}+\beta V_{e,i}+\varepsilon_{i}$. Then you may test whether $\alpha_+=\alpha_-=0$ or whether $\alpha_+<\alpha_-$, $\beta=1$ etc. However, you need to specify the model, i.e. need to make assumptions about $\varepsilon_i$. Moreover, you need more observations.

Comment: Indeed, and I have all reasons to believe that $\varepsilon_i$ will be normally distributed. However, I won't be able to obtain more data. One thing that bothers me is that using the reviewer's definition, a systematic and symmetrical overestimation (i.e. $\Delta V = \{ 4.5; ... ; 0; ...; -4.5 \}$) would yield a mean of zero and therefore not be detected. So what would you do given the limited data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you google "velocity versus speed" you can get that velocity is a vector, with speed being the magnitude of that vector. In your case the velocity is a vector pointing only along one direction. You are asked in this problem to check the velocity, not the speed, so $\Delta V=V_m-V_e$, not $\Delta V=|V_m|-|V_e|$.

Comment: I agree with your definition. However, the problem of no error detection in the case where $||V_e||$ is symmetrically overestimated (i.e. $\Delta V \in \{x;...;0;...;−x \}$) when using $\Delta V = V_m - V_e$ seems like a problem to me. How do you interpret such an issue?

Comment: In that case the **speed** is over/under estimated, not the velocity. Think of the problem in a similar way, if you have position and distance. You might overestimate your left/right position, or you might overestimate the distance from the origin